# In Paraview: comparative plotting of 3d surfaces with x,y,z data where z varies with time

Tags: time, 3d, surface, paraview

I have measured elevations of a surface at fixed time intervals. Now I have a set of X,Y,Z data for each time step. I am trying to plot a 3d surface from these X,Y,Z data for each time step in paraview and I want to show the change in elevation over time by changing the time frames in paraview.
I would be grateful if somebody can explain how can i do it?

Comment: First, can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: Yes Tim,
After reading other posts here, I managed to plot a 3d surface with data for one time step using delaunay2D. Now I can do same procedure to other data as well but I want to save them in one file with different time frames so that I will be able to show the changes over time.
And I also want to know if I can somehow do batch process these data since I am likely to have a lot of data over a long period.

Comment: You can store individual time steps in different files with a naming convention like `elevation0000.vtk`, `elevation0001.vtk, `elevation0002.vtk`, etc. Is that acceptable.

Comment: Also, are you X and Y coordinates arranged on a regular grid, or are they at arbitrary locations?

Comment: Thanks a lot Cory. The naming convention worked for me. But the surface generated with delaunay2D is triangulated and not smooth enough like a surface. Is there any way I can smooth up the surface? Btw the smooth filter did not work for me. and my data is not on a regular grid.